# How do I extract a variable from a UITable DidSelectAtRow?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an instance where a user picks from a UITable.  The selected record has a `name` and an `id` associated with it.

At the moment to verify the name and id are being correctly reported I am using

```
  let tempCountryId = (self.newCountries[cellCountryId!])
    print (tempCountryId)
```

> Country(name: Optional("England"), countryId: Optional("5"))

I want to be able to store that countryId in a variable so I can repopulate my UITable with data (Football Divisions) that match the countryId '5'

How do I do this?

This is my full script:

```
import UIKit

class PickTeamViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var teamsTableView: UITableView!

var pickedCountryID: Int?

var selectedCellCountryTitle: String?
var cellCountryId: Int?

struct Country {
    var name: String?
    var countryId: String?

    init(_ dictionary: [String : String]) {
        self.name = dictionary["name"]
        self.countryId = dictionary["id"]
    }
}


struct Divisions {
    var divisionName: String?
     var divisionId: String?
    init(_ dictionary: [String : String]) {

        self.divisionName = dictionary["name"]
        self.divisionId = dictionary["country_id"]
    }
}

struct Teams {
    var teamName: String?
    var newTeamId: String?

    init(_ dictionary: [String : String]) {
        self.teamName = dictionary["name"]

    }
}

struct TeamId {

    var newTeamId: String?

    init(_ dictionary: [String : String]) {
        self.newTeamId = dictionary["id"]

    }
}

var newCountries = [Country]()
var newDivisions = [Divisions]()
var newTeams = [Teams]()
var newTeamId = [TeamId]()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


    let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.quasisquest.uk/KeepScore/getTeams.php?");
    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!);
    request.httpMethod = "GET";

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: myUrl!) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {

                if error != nil {
                    print("error=\(error)")
                    return
                }

                do{
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any]
                    print (json)

                    if let arr = json?["countries"] as? [[String:String]] {
                        self.newCountries = arr.flatMap { Country($0) }
                        self.teamsTableView.reloadData()

                    }


                    if let arr = json?["divisions"] as? [[String:String]] {
                        self.newDivisions = arr.flatMap { Divisions($0) }

                    }




                    if let arr = json?["teams"] as? [[String:String]] {
                        self.newTeams = arr.flatMap { Teams($0) }

                    }


                    self.teamsTableView.reloadData()
                } catch{
                    print(error)
                }
        }
    }
    task.resume()


}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.newCountries.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let country = newCountries[indexPath.row]
    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    cell.textLabel?.text = country.name
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 12)
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    cellCountryId = indexPath.row
   // print (self.newCountries[cellCountryId!])
   let tempCountryId = (self.newCountries[cellCountryId!])
    print (tempCountryId)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.teamsTableView.delegate = self
     self.teamsTableView.dataSource = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


}
```

Comment: if the selected record is already in the selected record aka `TableViewCell` then where do you want to show it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  But Ideally, when the record is selected, that countryId '5' will be used to then refresh the UITable with data from a separate array that I also have stored

Comment: do you want to show the details of a country that is selected in the same `TableView`?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: I hope you know how `UITablevIew` its `DataSource` and `Delegate` work. If you want to show the details in the same `tableView` then it'll make the code of the the `dataSource` messy but it is doable. I'll endorse @matt's suggestion to show the details in a new `ViewController` as it makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks Adeel - I'll take your and Matts guidance and use a new ViewController

Comment: I still need to pull that countyId variable out so I can pass it in a segue - how do I store that particular countryId variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments you should use another view controller to show the details. In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method take out the selected country from `newCountries` array and pass it to the `DetailViewController`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let countryDetailsVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CountryDetailsViewController") as! DetailViewController
    countryDetailsVC.country = selectedCountry
    present(countryDetailsVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now that you have the country `Struct` you can show its details in the `DetailViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Your table is populated from the array `newCountries`. So, to replace the contents of the table, you would need to replace the contents of `newCountries` and reload the table.

But that is not a very wise strategy. It would be better to show a different view controller with a different table and a different data array.

Comment: Though I still need that variable I was initially asking about to be ale to pass it on to my next view controller...